# How is interaction with CDC device with no interface endpoints working?

Tags: arduino, usb, bootloader, libusb, libusb-1.0

I'm working on uploading to [Digispark board](http://digistump.com/products/1). It uses [micronucleus](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus) bootloader and i can see [uploader code](https://github.com/micronucleus/micronucleus/blob/master/commandline/library/micronucleus_lib.c). I've modified it a bit to see interfaces and endpoints count:

```
    nucleus->device = usb_open(dev);

    // added by me - start
    int interfaces, endpoints, j;
    struct usb_interface_descriptor *interface = NULL;

    interfaces = dev->config->bNumInterfaces;
    fprintf(stderr, "Found interfaces: %i\n", interfaces);

    interface = &(dev->config->interface[0].altsetting[0]);
    fprintf(stderr, "Endpoints: %i\n", interface->bNumEndpoints);
    // added by me - end

    // get nucleus info
    unsigned char buffer[4];
    int res = usb_control_msg(nucleus->device, USB_ENDPOINT_IN| USB_TYPE_VENDOR | USB_RECIP_DEVICE, 0, 0, 0, (char *)buffer, 4, MICRONUCLEUS_USB_TIMEOUT);
```

I wonder how it's working because interface #0 has no endpoints:

```
$./micronucleus --type intel-hex /tmp/Start.ino.hex 
> Please plug in the device ... 
> Press CTRL+C to terminate the program.
Found interfaces: 1
Endpoints: 0
> Device is found!
connecting: 40% complete
> Device has firmware version 1.6
> Available space for user applications: 6012 bytes
> Suggested sleep time between sending pages: 8ms
> Whole page count: 94  page size: 64
> Erase function sleep duration: 752ms
parsing: 60% complete
> Erasing the memory ...
erasing: 80% complete
> Starting to upload ...
writing: 100% complete
>> Micronucleus done. Thank you!
```

Usually i expect interface to have 2 endpoints (in & out from [usb.h](https://github.com/libusb/libusb-compat-0.1/blob/master/libusb/usb.h)):

```
#define USB_ENDPOINT_IN         0x80
#define USB_ENDPOINT_OUT        0x00
```

Can anyone explain me how `usb_control_msg(nucleus->device, USB_ENDPOINT_IN| USB_TYPE_VENDOR | USB_RECIP_DEVICE, 0, 0, 0, (char *)buffer, 4, MICRONUCLEUS_USB_TIMEOUT);` is working without endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/44026/8327.
In brief: it does not have endpoints (except 0) and interacts using control transfers only.